# "Certificate Import Error: Unknown error" when importing a certificate

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, chromium

I am using selenium/python/chromedriver to create a bot in Linux.
When importing a certificate at the chrome settings ("Your Certificate" tab), I get this error:

[image]

```
Certificate Import Error: Unknown error
```

I have the same versions (compatible) of normal Chrome and chrome driver. With Chrome I can import the same certificate with no problems.

I don't know if it's a browser restriction or if I am missing some flags.

I can't use headless mode.

I have tried adding flags, different browser settings, changing the certificate privileges...